# Pick a random name from a text file in VB

Tags: vb.net, file-io, random

I have a file that has names of competitors. I want to write a VB code that selects a random name from the file.What I need is show the names moving quickly once I press enter it will select the name. I hope you got the idea.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your problem correctly you want to show every names on the file to the user on a button which name is chances rapidly.
If you want to do this little trick you need to load all the names from the file at the begging and keep them in a array so you will not need to reconnect to the file, that contains your names, every time you change the name of the button
Once you get the names you will need to create an infinite loop and attach a timer so the loop will wait for a specific time to change the name of the button.
last thing that you need to do is write a set of code under the button. That breaks the loop and gives the name of the button which was the assigned name at the time of the clicking.
I hope that helps  you! 
Have a good day